# Given $L$ a complex finite dimensional Lie algebra. Then suppose $L$ is solvable. Show $L^{(1)}$ is nilpotent.

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

> Given $L$ a complex finite dimensional Lie algebra. Then suppose $L$ is solvable. Show $L^{(1)}$ is nilpotent.

Okay, so I have the existence of a flag of ideas in $L$. Can I deduce from this that $L$ is nilpotent?

Comment: Hint: By Lie's theorem, $L$ is isomorphic to a subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$ (for some $n$), consisting of upper triangular matrices. What kind of matrix do you get if you take the Lie bracket of two upper triangular matrices?

Comment: Thanks. This is identical to the way I did it, actually. I just thought it was a little messy, and hence was looking for possible more elegant ways.

Comment: Note that it will probably be hard to do it directly from working with the derived series of $L$, since in some way, it is hard to distinguish the various algebras in it (it is at least hard for me to say precisely what property of $L'$ it is we can extract and use for this, which we could not also say about $L$).